# Getting Error 2 when doing make dep

Tags: command-line

So I am trying to install VCV Rack and whenever I `make dep` it gives me this error

```
 wget -nc https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/releases/download/glew-2.1.0/glew-2.1.0.tgz
> File ‘glew-2.1.0.tgz’ already there; not retrieving.
> 
> tar xf glew-2.1.0.tgz
> make -C glew-2.1.0 glew.lib
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/marty/Rack/dep/glew-2.1.0'
> cc -shared -Wl,-soname=libGLEW.so.2.1 -o lib/libGLEW.so.2.1.0 tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lGL -lX11 
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [lib/libGLEW.so.2.1.0] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/marty/Rack/dep/glew-2.1.0'
bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: command substitution: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: make[1]:: command not found
(trusty)marty@localhost:~/Rack$ make[1]: *** [lib/libGLEW.so] Error 2
bash: make[1]:: command not found
(trusty)marty@localhost:~/Rack$ make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/marty/Rack/dep'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: First result in Google search: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL"

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this and there appears to be a number of required dependencies that are not detailed in the documentation. I found that the following were required:

- build-essential
- libx11-dev
- libgl1-mesa-dev
- libglu1-mesa-dev
- libxrandr-dev
- libxinerama-dev
- libxcursor-dev
- zlib1g-dev
- libasound2-dev
- libgtk2.0-dev

All went ok after these were installed.

These can all be installed using the command:

> sudo apt install build-essential libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev zlib1g-dev libasound2-dev libgtk2.0-dev

and then restart building the dependencies with `make dep`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a package that provides the libGL.so it's in the libgl1-mesa-dev package:

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```